# warnings.warn("Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test"

Tags: python, random-forest, data-mining

```
FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I am facing the above error after running the below code. Because of this I am getting 0.0 in Precision and F-score in classification report. Please help me in resolving this.

[image]

```
rfcl = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 500,random_state=0)
rfcl = rfcl.fit(X_train, train_labels)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

param_grid = {
    'max_depth': [7, 10],
    'max_features': [4, 6],
    'min_samples_leaf': [50, 100],
    'min_samples_split': [150, 300],
    'n_estimators': [301, 500]
}

rfcl = RandomForestClassifier()

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = rfcl, param_grid = param_grid, cv=3)


grid_search.fit(X_train, train_labels)
```

Answer (score -1):

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/81753/gridsearchcv-to-fine-tune-outputs-valueerror-and-fitfailedwarning

try printing

```
print(train_df.info()) print(test_df.info())
```

In my case, I used 0.0, 0,5 and 1.0 because I normalize 0 1 2.  When I changed to 0 1 2 my "y". Works!!!